# Does file_get_contents count as a pageview when grabbing data from an external URL?

Tags: php, google-analytics, pageviews

Im trying to read an external url's JSON LD data with php.  But, Im wondering if when I call:

`$html = file_get_contents( $url );`

will it count as a pageview for that $url through google analytics?  I don't want to drive up fake numbers.  If it does, is there a better way?

Comment: Easily testable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately it counts as a pageview. You cannot "preview" website code without HTTP request.